# Show value instead of aggregate in GCP Dashborad

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard

I want value instead of getting aggregation of the values in the line chart
Let say we are getting response of each second
10:00 - 1
10:01-2
10:03-4

My Y axis- 1,2,4
X Axis- 10:00,10:01,10:02
I want to plot y axis vesur x but in gcp dashboard i dont have option to directly use value but use aggregate function

Comment: Please include more details in your question; you can refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your post.

Comment: Apologies , i have edited it , could you please check and help